# How do I handle updated data in an API after local data persistence?

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room

I have a REST API containing a JSON Array of JSON Objects.

On the first launch of the Android application, the data is consumed through retrofit and stored using a Room database.

My question is: what do I do on the second launch? Do I systematically call and consume the API after each launch? Or is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to consume the API call if you stored that data already, what you can do is defining a timestamp variable inside your model class, and put any time value (you can add days or months) that should determine whether your app should fetch the data or not, if the time does't pass yet you can get the data from your local database, android documentation recommend using [NetworkBoundResource](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/88747993139224a4bb6dbe985adf652d557de621/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt) to handle this case, check it out it will help you a lot.